# Android list Activity data filling

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-activity

I have a list activity .I have created a array

```
string  []name = new String[50];
```

this string is used to populate the list 
but if i have data only till name[8] and i don't give values to the rest of the array and when i scroll till the end of the list the application force closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way would be to have a `List<String>` fill it with your names and pass it to the Adapter via `toArray`. However this may be not the cheapest way(in a sense of memory requirements).